# Criteria for when a function call can be reused?

Tags: db2, db2-11.5

I must admit I have not given it much thought previously, but I always assumed that a NOT DETERMINISTIC function would not be reused between function calls, Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST1()
RETURNS INT
CONTAINS SQL
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
NOT DETERMINISTIC
        RETURN VALUES INT(1000*RAND())
@
```

But if I try that as:

```
db2 "select test1() from ( values (1),(2) )"

1          
-----------
        868
        868
```

I get the same value for both 1 and 2. I assume this is because test1() is evaluated once and the result is reused for both 1 and 2. I thought not deterministic would prevent this, but apparently, I was wrong. If I instead create the function as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST2()
RETURNS INT
CONTAINS SQL
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN ATOMIC
        RETURN VALUES INT(1000*RAND());
END @


db2 "select test2() from ( values (1),(2) )"

1          
-----------
        596
         16
```

It behaves as I would have expected.

Any links to docs that can shed some light on this?

EDIT: Yet another simplified scenario, but closer to the real deal

```
CREATE TABLE T ( X INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ) @

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST3()
RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
NOT DETERMINISTIC
        RETURN
            WITH TT (X,N) AS (
                VALUES (INT(1000*RAND()),0)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT INT(1000*RAND()), N+1
                FROM TT, T
                WHERE N < 10000 AND T.X = TT.X
            )
            SELECT X FROM TT
            WHERE N = (SELECT MAX(N) FROM TT)
@

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST4()
RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN ATOMIC
        RETURN
            WITH TT (X,N) AS (
                VALUES (INT(1000*RAND()),0)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT INT(1000*RAND()), N+1
                FROM TT, T
                WHERE N < 10000 AND T.X = TT.X
            )
            SELECT X FROM TT
            WHERE N = (SELECT MAX(N) FROM TT);
END @


db2 "select test3() from ( values (1),(2) )"

1          
-----------
        320
        320

db2 "select test4() from ( values (1),(2) )"

1          
-----------
        846
        836
```

I don't mind using BEGIN ATOMIC in my function definition, I'm mostly curious why db2 reuses the value from a not deterministic function

EDIT2: From the plan it appears as if test3 is inlined (that I would have expected from a deterministic function without a begin atomic block)

```
Optimized Statement:
-------------------
SELECT 
  (SELECT 
     Q11.$C0 
   FROM 
     (SELECT 
        MAX(Q9.$C0) 
      FROM 
        (SELECT 
           Q8.$C1 
         FROM 
           (SELECT 
              INT((+1.00000000000000E+003 * RAND())),
              (Q4.$C1 + 1) 
            FROM 
              DB2INST1.T AS Q3,
              Q8 AS Q4 
            WHERE 
              (Q3.X = Q4.$C0) AND 
              (Q4.$C1 < 10000) 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT 
              INT((+1.00000000000000E+003 * RAND())),
              0 
            FROM 
              (VALUES 
                 1) AS Q6
           ) AS Q8 
         WHERE 
           Q8.$C1 IS NOT NULL
        ) AS Q9
     ) AS Q10,
     Q8 AS Q11 
   WHERE 
     (Q11.$C1 = Q10.$C0)
  ) 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
     $INTERNAL_FUNC$() 
   FROM 
     (VALUES 
        1,
        2) AS Q1
  ) AS Q2
```

Comment: Does it change if you `RETURN  INT(1000*RAND())`?

Comment: The problem is in `VALUES`. Use single `RETURN 1000*RAND()`.

Comment: Ah, I see. It was a simplified query. The actual query does a select from a CTE. Ill update my example